# CLKComplicationDataSource: getTimelineEntries delegate called hundreds of times

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch-complication, time-travel

I am trying to support TimeTravel in a Watch app Complication.
Consider this code.

I cannot understand why these delegate methods are called repeatedly, until I kill the app.

I wonder what I could be doing wrong, since the OS is responsible for calling these methods. Is this some kind of WatchOS bug?

```
func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, after date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([    CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
    // Call the handler with the timeline entries after to the given date

    let interval = stride(from:0.0, through:60, by: 10.0)

    var entries: [CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]? = nil

    switch complication.family {

    case .circularSmall:
        entries = interval.flatMap({ minutes in
            entryForCircularSmall(date: date.addingTimeInterval(60.0 * minutes) )
        })
        handler(entries)

    case .utilitarianLarge:
        entries = interval.flatMap({ minutes in
            entryForUtilitarianLarge( date: date.addingTimeInterval(60.0 * minutes) )
        })

        handler(entries)

    default:
        handler(nil)
    }

    print("future timelineEntries limit: \(limit), date: \(date), entries: \(entries?.count)")
}

func getTimelineEndDate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (Date?) -> Void) {
    let date = Date().addingTimeInterval(60.0 * Double(240))
    print("timeline end: \(date)")
    handler(date)
}
```

Small excerpt from the console log:

```
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:32:59 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:09 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:09 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
future timelineEntries limit: 100, date: 2017-02-09 23:33:10 +0000, entries: Optional(7)
timeline end: 2017-02-10 03:33:10 +0000
```

At this point, I kill the app...

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the delegate was called too many times, because I would keep supplying timeline entries for the same date.

I had a bug in my code (not shown here) responsible for creating the CLKComplicationTimelineEntry objects. Instead of using the date supplied by the delegate, I was using a call to Date() (apparently copy-pasted from the implementation of the `getCurrentTimelineEntry` method).

I find impressive however that WatchOS would call the delegate **thousands** of times.

Comment: Good tip, I had a similar issue that was invoking this delegate about 10 times. I removed calling to Date() within the delegate, and now it still calls this delegate twice. Is that normal or should it only be one call?

Answer (score 0):

I find another cause for this. The entries you return for the handler needs to span at least 25 hours, otherwise the `getTimelineEntries` will keep calling until it gets enough entries.

```
func getTimelineEntries(for complication: CLKComplication, after date: Date, limit: Int, withHandler handler: @escaping ([CLKComplicationTimelineEntry]?) -> Void) {
    var entries: [CLKComplicationTimelineEntry] = // .... some code
    handler(entries)
}
```